# WPF/Caliburn.Micro - Input Validation using IDataErrorInfo

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, idataerrorinfo

I have following code in my WPF application and I'm trying to implement input validation.

Model:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class CustomerViewModel : Screen, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private Customer _customer;
    public Customer Customer
    {
        get { return _customer; }
        set
        {
            if (_customer != value)
            {
                _customer = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Customer);
            }
        }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = null;
            if (columnName == "Name")
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Customer.Name))
                    result = "Please enter a Name";
                if (Customer.Name.Length < 3)
                    result = "Name is too short";
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Customer.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}"/>
```

**Problem:**
The solution is not working as expected. Nothing happens when type data in Textbox. I'm not sure weather I have followed the right steps.

Could any one help me?

Comment: How about trying `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`?

Answer (score 1):

I presume the problem occurs because there is no `Name` property in your view model (but inside the `Customer` class).
Your work with a nested property in your binding `Customer.Name`.

I have not used this in combination with `IDataErrorInfo` validation.

Currently this condition inside you view model indexer will not be hit:

```
if (columnName == "Name")
{
...
}
```

because the indexer is never called.

**My suggestion**

Add a `Name` property to your view model which will represent the customers name.
You can then initialize your view model with the customer class like setting

```
Name = customer.Name
```

in the view models constructor.

Your binding would need to change to

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name  ....
```

After doing this, the indexer should be working, because now there is a `Name` property in your view model.

Perhaps there is another solution which would let you keep you current nested binding (`Customer.Name`), but I do not know this for sure.

Comment: Pretty sure this is the situation since Customer doesn't have INotifyDataErrorInfo/IDataErrorInfo inherited, the error handling doesn't bubble.  If you go the model route on top of the viewmodel route expect twice the code.  The convention built into the ConventionManager explicitly looks for the INotifyDataErrorInfo/IDataErrorInfo interface(s) and binds the ValidatesOnError and NotifyOnValidationErrors to true.  Doing the validation with properties in the viewmodel then assigning results to the object in question is easier.